# Excel without Macro Slot Machine

Tags: excel

This question is a slot machine which displays 3 combination of images.

The question states that if the slot machine displays a set of images of A,B,C, the person will win.

I have understood that there are 6 different cases that might occur so that the person will win.

1. If 1st image = A, 2nd image = B, 3rd image = C
2. If 1st image = A, 2nd image = C, 3rd image = B
3. If 1st image = B, 2nd image = C, 3rd image = A
4. If 1st image = B, 2nd image = A, 3rd image = C
5. If 1st image = C, 2nd image = B, 3rd image = A
6. If 1st image = C, 2nd image = A, 3rd image = B

My current formula in the excel is extremely long which consist of 6 IF and 6 AND function. I am new to excel and would like to ask if there's another way to solve this question or some other function instead?

Comment: what is your current formula, withouth that we can't see if it is long? Also what do the cells look like, are they just A, B and C? or really images? Shortest would be to check if A is present only once, and if B is present only once. For that concatenate the three values into one string.

Comment: The current formula consist of IF(AND(G76="A",H76="B",I76="C"),Win, IF(AND(G76="A",H76="C",I76="B"),Win,IF(AND(.........))))))

And then it keeps going on and on, for 6 different cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tries to find `A` and `B` and `C` in the range, if any are missing then it will error and return `Lose`:

```
=IF(isnumber(MATCH("A",G76:I76,0)+MATCH("B",G76:I76,0)+MATCH("C",G76:I76,0)),"Win","Lose")
```

Or:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(FIND({"A","B","C"},G176&H176&I176))),"Win","Lose")
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much, it is working, i will definitely check out the functions to understand this formula.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=IF(AND(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(G76&H76&I76,"A",""))=2,LEN(SUBSTITUTE(G76&H76&I76,"B",""))=2,LEN(SUBSTITUTE(G76&H76&I76,"C",""))=2),"Win","Lose")
```

It checks if A, B and C are all present only once. If so you win, else you lose.

Comment: Hi, i have tried your method but its not working, not sure what is wrong, but Scott's answer is working. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Should work now. I replaced ; with , As my own excel uses a different locale. Also forgot one , in the code when I first assumed there were only A, B and C but you commented that there were more letters. I had to add a check for C because of that.

Comment: Hi, thank you, just tested with your method, it is working as well. This is definitely another alternative method.